# How to handle missing param in route? Express

Tags: node.js, express

How do I handle a route that has a parameter, and if the client fails to include it, not let the server error out.

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  let profileID = req.params.id
  if (profileID) {
    res.send('ID provided');
  } else {
    res.send('No id provided');
  }
});
```

If the ID parameter is provided I want to use it somewhere. But if it is missing, I want there to be a default behaviour to fall back to (ie. Route to another page, some message, etc)

The expected behavior is:

> http://example.com/ routes to a landing page

But if a trailing ID is provided

> http://example.com/abc123 routes to a specific profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `router.get('/:id?')` and then id will be marked as an optional param.

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-express-server-s7vrc?file=/src/view/hello.html)

#### Express Server Example

```js
// the question mark marks the parameter as optional
app.get("/:id?", (req, res) => {

  // will create an id entry even if none is provided
  console.log(req.params);

  // if there is an id do something else 
  if (req.params.id) return res.send(req.params.id);

  // if there is no id default behaviour for '/' route
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/view/hello.html");
});
```